# Imagem não consegue ser carregada na aplicação

Tags: ionic2, angular

A imagem aparece normal ao rodar no "ionic serve" mas quando rodo em um device `ionic run android --device` ela não consegue ser carregada, estranho que eu coloquei um alt na tag img e só consegue ser exibido o alt, já tentei tirar mas não aparece nada.
A minha tag está assim :

```
<img src="../assets/img/logomarcaSaf.png" class="logo" (click)="infor()">
```

O que poderia estar causando o mau carregamento da imagem? Tenho outra como background que é bem mais pesada e aparece normalmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce deve colocar a imagem direto da pasta assets, se me recordo bem.

Tenta assim:

```
<img src="/assets/img/logomarcaSaf.png" class="logo" (click)="infor()">
```

ou assim:

```
<img src="assets/img/logomarcaSaf.png" class="logo" (click)="infor()">
```

Quando o ionic compila a app ele joga para a pasta build e o acesso é feito por la, ao usar o ../ ele perde a referencia da pasta correta.

Comment: Funcionou, mas só não entendi o seguinte, é que eu tenho no diretório src/app/app.scss um  'background-image: url(../assets/img/bgc2.png);" e funciona normal tanto no navegador como no device, esse arquivo é compilado em uma pasta diferente ?

Comment: Desculpe amigo mas eu não sei te responder.